# Using affidavit to show Proof of ties for Visa application, Real Estate Document

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens, proof-of-ties

I have written a Letter of Explanation detailing my intents on visiting Canada. But one of the things I needed to be sure about was documentation. Now See something like this

I have declared that I have a landed property (Real Estate property), And it was passed down to my father from my grand father, and my father passed it on to me to handle.
I declared this as some tie to my home country, is there a need for a sworn affidavit? Or i just merge it as one of the documents I need together with my letter of Explanation and submit? Just needed to be very sure here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to include is a document that proves that you own the land, such as the Certificate of Occupancy, or the Deed of Assignment, showing that you are the property owner.

Comment: its passed on from grand father , to my father , then on to me... thats why i am worried

Comment: @Adam I don't know how inherited properties are handled in Nigeria, but certainly there is some procedure where the transfer is registered with the government? This will generate a document, and that registration is what you should look for.

Comment: I'd have to go over to court on Monday to See what I can do about this.